# I can't find a way to filter using PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, pagedlist

Well, I assume my problem it's actually pretty simple.
This is my second table... The first one took like 3 minutes to load. Looking for a way to make it faster I found this: [using a nuget](https://libraries.io/nuget/PagedList.Mvc/4.5.0).
But I can't make it filter my records.
It does filter them once and show the first page filtered, but when I click on any page it doesn't filter anymore.
In the bottom of the partial view (where my table is displayed) I have the helper method that filters. In here I just send the page alone to the controller... but in the View (Index) is where I filter them by brand who also send the brand alone to the controller.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string brand_name, int? page)
        {
            //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?
            //var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts();
            ViewData["brand_name"] = brand_name;
            // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
            var pageNumber = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;

            //ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brand_name))
            {
                // will only contain 12 products max because of the pageSize
                IPagedList<Material> onePageOfProducts = db.EContent_MaterialsFinalViewWithBcos
                    .Select(i => new Material
                    {
                        Brand = i.Brand,
                        Category = i.Category,
                        Language = i.Language,
                        Bco = i.Bco,
                        MaterialCod = i.MaterialCod,
                        Derivation = i.Derivation,
                        Artwork = i.Artwork,
                        BcoDelivery = i.BcoDelivery,
                        MaterialId = i.MaterialId
                    })
                    .Where(p => p.Brand.ToLower() == brand_name.ToLower())
                    .OrderBy(i => i.MaterialCod)
                    .ToPagedList<Material>(pageNumber, defaultPageSize);

                return View("Index", onePageOfProducts);
            }
            else
            {
                // will only contain 12 products max because of the pageSize
                IPagedList<Material> onePageOfProducts = db.EContent_MaterialsFinalViewWithBcos
                    .Select(i => new Material
                    {
                        Brand = i.Brand,
                        Category = i.Category,
                        Language = i.Language,
                        Bco = i.Bco,
                        MaterialCod = i.MaterialCod,
                        Derivation = i.Derivation,
                        Artwork = i.Artwork,
                        BcoDelivery = i.BcoDelivery,
                        MaterialId = i.MaterialId
                    }).OrderBy(i => i.MaterialCod).ToPagedList<Material>(pageNumber, defaultPageSize);

                return View("Index", onePageOfProducts);
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc <!--import this so we get our HTML Helper-->

@model IPagedList<eContentMVC.Models.Material>

<div style="padding-top: 5px"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Materials", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
            </span>
            <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" name="brand_name" placeholder="Search Brand for..." />                 
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
    <div style="padding-top: 20px"></div>
    <div id="grid-list">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_AjaxMaterialList", Model); }
    </div>    
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc <!--import this so we get our HTML Helper-->

@model IPagedList<eContentMVC.Models.Material>

<table>Some table here</table>
<div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
    <div class="centerAlign">
        <!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Materials", new
       {
           //It would be awesome if I could have some brand_name = brand
           page
       }))
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on another page number, you are getting brand_name => null or empty, in the controller. I see you are storing brand_name in the ViewData, so you can retrieve it again in the view, and show it in the TextBox, so it is always sent to the controller along with the page number. You can do it this way:

```
<input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" name="brand_name" placeholder="Search Brand for..." value="@ViewData["brand_name"]"/>
```

Comment: Just by adding this it didn't work out. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added `brand_name = Request["brand_name"],` in the `PagedListPager` helper on the Partial View and it worked out. Thanks! Answer accepted.